# BeautifulSoup4 (Parsing) and "find" : why some tags can be "found" and some cannot be "found"?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing, lxml

Look at this example :

```
#pip install bs4
#pip install lxml

import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_doc="""
<A1 xmi:type="diagram:D" uid="_sdfsdf" name="BIGWORD" outgoingEdges="_fdsfsdf" AA="7" BB="7" CC="NEW">
      <target xmi:type="O2" href="EO2"/>
      <semanticElements xmi:type="O2" href="EO2"/>
      <AR>K_L</AR>
      <AR>K_S</AR>
      <AR>K_R</AR>
      <OW xmi:type="diagram:S" uid="_sdgfsdfsdf" borderSize="1" bor="1" bc="9,92,46" lab="node" color="197,255,166">
        <description xmi:type="style:S" href="PP[name='AL']/@ownedR[name='gol']/@default/@node[name='LBF']/@style"/>
      </OW>
      <description xmi:type="style:S" href="PP[name='AL']/@ownedR[name='gol']/@default/@node[name='LBF']/@style"/>
      </OW>
      <description2 id="fd">
      <description2 id="fd2">
      <actualMapping xmi:type="description_1:NodeM" href="PP[name='AL']/@ownedR[name='gol']/@default/@node[name='LBF']"/>
    </A1>
    """

soup=BeautifulSoup(xml_doc,'lxml')

test1=soup.find("target")
print(test1) #<target href="EO2" xmi:type="O2"></target>

test2=soup.find("OW",AA="7")
print(test2) #None, why? Why did test one work fine and test would not?

test3=soup.find("A1")
print(test3) #Nothing
```

Why does the tag "target" seem to be always "found" by the find method. And when i try to work with "A1 tag" or "OW tag", it never works! I always get a None.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You have one `<OW>` but two `</OW>`. That's not valid XML.

Comment: The `<OW>` element doesn't have an `AA` attribute. Why do you think `find("OW", AA="7")` should find anything?

Comment: Hello @Barmar , i put put because i had added it in the xml code to test, but EVEN if it's in theme, test2=soup.find("OW",AA="7") would not work. And if you use test2=soup.find("OW"), it still will not work.
As for the extra</OW> you are right, i think it's because i copy pasted the "description" tag and took an extra /ow on the way, wel guess what, removed that extra /ow and the description above it. (i was left with one OW tag and 2 description tags.) well --> NO RESULT with : test3=soup.find("OW").... Please try it and see.

Comment: I found the solution : i had to write "ow" instead of "OW" (capital)

Comment: you should post that as an answer.

Comment: done, i don't know how to edit the post to be (answered)

Comment: Put your solution in the **Your Answer** box below.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution elsewhere: I had to write "ow" instead of "OW" (capital), and it goes for attributes aswell.